# How to write access to default /etc/init.d

Tags: ubuntu, sysvinit, bioinformatics

I am trying to install [Proteios](http://www.proteios.org/trac/wiki/NewLinuxInstall) software in Ubuntu 16. One of the requirement for this software is

- (*) Write access to $SERVICE_PATH(default /etc/init.d)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instructions say that the installation script should be run as root: at that point it should have full write access to everything.

If the software does not run as root and still needs access to `/etc/init.d` after the installation, **that is very unusual** but can be arranged if really needed:

1.) Create a group. You can name it however you want. Option `-r` creates it using the GID number range allocated for system groups, so it won't get mixed up with groups associated with normal users:

```
sudo groupadd -r proteios
```

2.) Add the user that needs write access to `/etc/init.d` to that group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G proteios someuser
```

3.) Assign group ownership in `/etc/init.d` to the new group. If more than one user needs this, just repeat this step as many times as needed:

```
sudo chgrp -R proteios /etc/init.d
```

4.) Assign group write access:

```
sudo chmod -R g+rwX /etc/init.d
```

5.) Make sure all new files created in that directory will be owned by the `proteios` group by default:

```
sudo chmod g+s /etc/init.d
```

I would prefer doing all this in a throw-away virtual machine first, to see what this Proteios software actually wants to do with `/etc/init.d`. This software seems to have a built-in assumption that the computer where Proteios is installed will only be used for Proteios and nothing else, and so it does not need to care much for security or standard conventions - a dangerous assumption.

---

If it turns out the software wants only to modify its own start-up script, but does it in such a way that write access to just the script itself is not enough (e.g. it wants to backup the old file before creating a new one), then I might **not** add permissions to the real `/etc/init.d`, but instead try redirecting the application by creating a directory with suitable permissions somewhere else (e.g. `/opt/proteios/etc/init.d`), adding

```
export SERVICE_PATH=/opt/proteios/etc/init.d
```

to the beginning of Proteios startup script and to the environment of any user that uses Proteios, and then creating symbolic link from (each) Proteios start-up script created in the custom directory back to the real `/etc/init.d`:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/proteios/etc/init.d/* /etc/init.d/
```

This way, Proteios can modify its own files as much as it likes, but cannot modify other system services. If it wants to add other, previously unknown start-up scripts, the administrator will need to create symbolic links for them if those scripts need to actually start at boot time. This should prevent users from manipulating other system services through Proteios.

Answer (score 0):

The prerequisite is to *have* write access to `$SERVICE_PATH` (`/etc/init.d` by default) *and* to `$CATALINA_HOME`.

The documentation does not say what user you should run the commands as, but that user need to either own those two paths, be part of a group that has write access to those paths, or switch to the root account when running the commands that needs to write to those paths.

For example, the documentation says to edit the `config` file in `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/proteios/WEB-INF`.  To do that, the configuration file has to be writable by the user that edits the file.

It is not explicitly said what other steps that needs to write to these paths, but my guess is that running the mentioned `install`, `update` and `init` scripts may require this (the instructions do say to run these as root).